# Two machines on the network with the same hostname

Tags: ubuntu, hostname

There are two machines on my network that have the same hostname. I verified it by typing

`# hostname`

on the terminal. The effect is that I can only view one of the two machines on the Network, from Nautilus. One machine is Ubuntu 10.04 and the other is 9.10.

I tried

```
# sudo hostname newName
```

and restarted the machine, but the name remains the same. What should I do to change the hostname?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to set hostname in ubuntu is to update the hostname file. This is true for most linux distributions.

```
emacs /etc/hostname
```

For more information see

```
man hostname
```

Comment: also works with "vi /etc/hostname" ;-)

Comment: Or ed, vim, nano, pico, or butterflies ;) +1

Comment: nano is fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

you need to change it in:

/etc/sysconfig/network

HOSTNAME="plain.domainname.com"

for a perminant change

Comment: Debian-based Ubuntu does not have `/etc/sysconfig/network`. You're thinking of redhat/centos/fedora.

Comment: yeah, I couldnt find the mentioned file at the location.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old now, at this point the accepted answers are correct for non-systemd based distros, but on a systemd machine you would use `hostnamectl hostname [new hstname]` to set the hostname.